# google maps iframe on cordova, tablet and ios problems

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, cordova, google-maps

I am using a cordova application, for the maps i let the clients download the "iframe"snippet from the backend of a website using ajax calls. I have to do this because the owner has to upload the code for the different maps. So the problem is this works like a charm on mobiles, but in samsung galaxy tab 3 and on iphone the maps are not showing. The iframe is charging but is empty. (i think the map is not rendering)

Answer (score 1):

Check your error console, if it appears something like that:

```
ERROR Internal navigation rejected - <allow-navigation> not set for url='http://maps.google.com
```

Just put that on the config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

That worked for me